# What is the relationship called between two sets that are both members of all the same sets?

Tags: terminology

Is there terminology for the relationship $\forall C(C\in D\implies(A\in C \iff B \in C))$ between $A$ and $B$, for some $D$?

I'm looking for a single word, or something shorthand for what's written in the title.

I assume the answer may be quite obvious, but I'm blanking at the moment. If there isn't such terminology, for shame!

Comment: Possibly "$A$ and $B$ are not separated by $D$" or "$A$ and $B$ are not distinguished by $D$".  Not sure if I would use these without explanation though.

Comment: I don't know any such terminology. I'd say "$D$-equal" or that the sets "agree on $D$".

Comment: In view of Leibniz's concept of the [identity of indiscernibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles), one might abbreviate the proposition as "$A$ and $B$ are $D$-indiscernible", but I agree with the comment that this usage would have to be defined.